# Flex child 100% height is not respected by the img contained with height 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following flex arrangement. The img displays the image at its original height. When the img tag is assigned the #child tag directly as a child to #parent, then it respects the parent's height of 100vh. I can't understand why 100% of the child is not being carried over to the img tag which also has height set to 100%.

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#parent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
}

#child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
}

#child img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <img src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/flower-color-400x391.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First you need to fix your selectors? Your css selectors does not match with html elements.

Answer (score 0):

It works in `#child` because there is a height defined. It knows to take `100%` of the height of the parent which is `#container`. You can set `height: inherit;` without the `#child` div and it will inherit it from its closest ancestor that has a height defined.

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#parent {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But in my example height is defined as well to be 100%.